# How do I delete a local repository in git?

Tags: git

I can't find the command. I tried Googling "git 'delete a repository'".

Comment: This [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-to-remove-repository-from-local-without-removing-it-from/qaq-p/186628) might help.

Answer (score 664, accepted):

Delete the `.git` directory in the root-directory of your repository if you only want to delete the git-related information (branches, versions).

If you want to delete everything (git-data, code, etc), just delete the whole directory.

.git directories are hidden by default, so you'll need to be able to view hidden files to delete it.

Comment: This WOULD delete the files if they aren't in use, but so long as Git locks them, it won't work so this does not answer "how to delete a local repo".

Comment: @rainabba, Why would Git be locking them in the first place? Close your Git app.

Comment: How do you 'close your Git app'? Anyway, it's seemingly about permission rather than app lockdown. In Ubuntu: `sudo rm -r directory`.

Comment: What if there is no .git directory?

Comment: @JozemiteApps If there is no .git directory, there is no repository. Run `ls -a` to see hidden files.

Comment: to unhide folder in mac-> just use Command + Shift + .

Comment: @Pacerier Oh yes, because closing apps in windows closes the processes.... likewise with delete, I'm trying to rename a local repo directory, but windows is having none of it because it's "in use"

Answer (score 350):

To piggyback on [rkj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1514088/1507392), to avoid endless prompts (and force the command recursively), enter the following into the command line, within the project folder:

```
$ rm -rf .git
```

Or to delete .gitignore and .gitmodules if any (via @aragaer):

```
$ rm -rf .git*
```

Then from the same ex-repository folder, to see if hidden folder .git is still there:

```
$ ls -lah
```

If it's not, then congratulations, you've deleted your local git repo, but not a remote one if you had it. You can delete GitHub repo on their site (github.com).

To view hidden folders in Finder (Mac OS X) execute these two commands in your terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

Source: http://lifehacker.com/188892/show-hidden-files-in-finder.

Comment: It's not only to avoid prompts, rm -rf was necessary for me otherwise rm would not delete files and complain:
rm: cannot remove `.git/objects/pack': Directory not empty

Comment: Yes, -r is for recursive and -f is for force. So you are forcing and doing recursive deletion.

Comment: I'd actually suggest deleting `.git*` to also remove `.gitignore` and `.gitmodules` if any.

Comment: Thanks) its work great ,for windows in project folder run  rm -rf .git

Comment: " -r is for recursive" that means you tell the guy to delete the entire repo struct just because he created one in a wrong place higher in the directory structure

Answer (score 64):

In the repository directory you remove the directory named **.git**
 and that's all :). On Un*x it is hidden, so you might not see it from file browser, but

```
cd repository-path/
rm -r .git
```

should do the trick.

Comment: you'll want to use "rm -rf .git" or you'll be pressing "y" to confirm for every single file in the directory.

Comment: @BrentSandstrom, absolutely right!

Answer (score 7):

That's right, if you're on a mac(unix) you won't see .git in finder(the file browser). You can follow the directions above to delete and there are git commands that allow you to delete files as well(they are sometimes difficult to work with and learn, for example: on making a 'git rm -r ' command you might be prompted with a .git/ not found.  Here is the git command specs:

usage: git rm [options] [--] ...

```
-n, --dry-run         dry run
-q, --quiet           do not list removed files
--cached              only remove from the index
-f, --force           override the up-to-date check
-r                    allow recursive removal
--ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
```

When I had to do this, deleting the objects and refs didn't matter. After I deleted the other files in the .git, I initialized a git repo with 'git init' and it created an empty repo.

Comment: That's not 100% true. I'm on Mac OS X and I can see `.git` and other hidden/system folder easily (e.g., `.DS_Store`). All you need to do is to configure Finder. Here is how: http://lifehacker.com/188892/show-hidden-files-in-finder. `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` and then `killall Finder`.

Comment: Yes that's right, you can configure finder to show hidden files, as well as you can configure editors to show hidden folders. The lesson here is that everything that begins with a '.' is a usually a hidden folder/file.

Comment: Actually, for OS X you can use the key combination Shift-Command-[period] to  show or hide hidden files or directories - much easier than entering those commands into terminal!