# Why is git erroring with 'Assertion failed' on git add .?

Tags: xcode, git

I forked a repo, then cloned it to my Mac into a `/YATC` directory. I had a previously-created Xcode project (TwitterTimeline) in another directory, which I copied into the `/YATC directory`. I did `git add .` in the /YATC directory, and only an empty TwitterTimeline directory was added to the repo. No other files were added. I later found out that there was already a `.git` directory in TwitterTimeline. I think Xcode must have created that, although I don't recall ever asking it to.

Anyway, I deleted the `TwitterTimeline/.git` directory.  I went back up to `/YATC` and tried to do `git add .` there, and nothing happened. Meaning I immediately did `git status`, and it said there was nothing to commit. Then I went down to the TwitterTimeline directory and did `git add .`, and got the following:

```
Assertion failed: (item->nowildcard_len <= item->len && item->prefix <= item->len), function prefix_pathspec, file pathspec.c, line 308.
Abort trap: 6
```

What is this?

Answer (score 34):

Not sure exactly what's happening but I was in the same situation

1. I moved one git repo inside another
2. deleted the .git dir thinking it would become a regular subdir
3. tried to `git add -A .`
4. got the weird error message

I got around it by renaming the subdir, doing `git add` from a parent dir, then renaming the subdir back to the original name. Somehow that seemed to get git back in a working state.

Comment: In my case, I forgot that empty directory to which I was adding is  a submodule (did not run `git submodule update` after cloning). And when I copied the content to empty folder and tried to `git add .`, I got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the problem is known and it usually affects submodules. It's not Git bug, but basically instead of assert you should see the proper error that specific *pathspec* is part of the submodule.

The following Git [patch](https://public-inbox.org/git/20161229192908.32633-1-sbeller@google.com/) from Stefan Beller fixes that problem:

```
--- a/pathspec.c
+++ b/pathspec.c
@@ -313,8 +313,23 @@ static unsigned prefix_pathspec(struct pathspec_item *item,
    }

    /* sanity checks, pathspec matchers assume these are sane */
-   assert(item->nowildcard_len <= item->len &&
-          item->prefix         <= item->len);
+   if (item->nowildcard_len > item->len ||
+       item->prefix         > item->len) {
+       /* Historically this always was a submodule issue */
+       for (i = 0; i < active_nr; i++) {
+           struct cache_entry *ce = active_cache[i];
+           int ce_len = ce_namelen(ce);
+           int len = ce_len < item->len ? ce_len : item->len;
+           if (!S_ISGITLINK(ce->ce_mode))
+               continue;
+           if (!memcmp(ce->name, item->match, len))
+               die (_("Pathspec '%s' is in submodule '%.*s'"),
+                   item->original, ce_len, ce->name);
+       }
+       /* The error is a new unknown bug */
+       die ("BUG: item->nowildcard_len > item->len || item->prefix > item->len)");
+   }
+
    return magic;
 }
```

One of the reason could be that the directory where you're adding the files is still registered as a submodule in the index, but actually it's not a valid git repository (e.g. it's missing `.git` directory).

So you should either:

- initialize and update your submodules by:

  ```
   git submodule init
   git submodule update
  ```

  <sup>Run from the parent directory where you had the error.</sup>

  Make sure all non-initialized submodules have empty directories, so move any files out of there temporary.
- or if you don't need this submodule, remove it:

  ```
  git rm -f --cached subrepo
  ```

  <sup>Run from the parent directory where you had the error.</sup>

Then try adding the files again.

---

See also:

- [[PATCH] pathspec: give better message for submodule related pathspec error](https://public-inbox.org/git/20161229192908.32633-1-sbeller@google.com/)
- [Re: [PATCH] pathspec: adjust prefixlen after striping trailing slash](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg249473.html)
- [assert failed in submodule edge case](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/assert-failed-in-submodule-edge-case-td7628687.html),
- ["item->nowildcard_len"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22item-%3Enowildcard_len%22) in Google.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too,Here is my way to fix this:

1. delete the .git folder in the submodule folder(if you did this before, go 2)
2. then excute follow command, directory is your submodule folder

   `git rm --cached directory
   git add directory`
3. then you can upload this folder like others

Answer (score 0):

The only way i was able to get around this error, after

- Deleting the .git folder
- `git deinit`
- `git rm`
- going over these links  [git fatal pathspec submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472596/git-fatal-pathspec-is-in-submodule)  ,  [deleting local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514054/how-do-i-delete-a-local-repository-in-git) ,  [assert failed in submodule](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/assert-failed-in-submodule-edge-case-td7628687.html)

was to rename directory and then add it again.