# Git: fatal: Pathspec is in submodule

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-submodules, hakyll

I'm trying to get TravisCI to automatically deploy my Hakyll static site, according to [this guide](http://timbaumann.info/posts/2013-08-04-hakyll-github-and-travis.html).

Here's how my repo is set up. I have my source branch, which contains my hakyll and markdown files. It builds the html into the `_site` directory, which is set up as a submodule, linked to my `master` branch.

I build the site without problem, then `cd` into the _site directory. However, when I try to `git add ./*` the newly generated HTML files, I get the following error:

```
fatal: Pathspec './about.html' is in submodule '_site'
```

When I try `git add --all`, I get this error:

```
git: pathspec.c:317: prefix_pathspec: Assertion `item->nowildcard_len <= item->len && item->prefix <= item->len' failed.

/home/travis/build.sh: line 245: 1566 Aborted git add --all
```

What is causing this, and how can I avoid this?

You can view the repository [here](https://github.com/JoeyEremondi/JoeyEremondi.github.io/tree/source).

Comment: it might be duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458306/git-rm-fatal-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files be aware the could be a problem of permissions on files https://stackoverflow.com/a/67315740/778517

Answer (score 582, accepted):

Removing the directory from git and adding it again worked for me:

```
 git rm --cached directory
 git add directory
```

This works if you purposefully removed the `.git` directory because you wanted to add `directory` to your main git project. In my specific case, I had git cloned an extension and ran `git add .` without thinking too much. Git decided to create a submodule, which I didn't like. So I removed `directory/.git` and ran into `Git: fatal: Pathspec is in submodule`. I couldn't find out how to remove the submodule stuff. Fixed with the two lines above.

Comment: This solved an issue I had where I accidentally pulled down a project into an existing project, creating a submodule. I had tried just about every other suggestion out there. Removing the directory and adding again addressed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have .git and see it! But when I want to commit some files that located in a folder, it shows an error "blahblah did not match any file(s) known to git"

Comment: This fixed the issue. In my case, I cloned the project in another machine.

Comment: I was having the same problem with a Visual Studio project which I synch with GitHub. The folder where most of my development is taking place wasn't being tracked, and if I tried adding it I was getting the same error. This solution fixed it for me too!

Comment: THANK. YOU!!! Took me two days to figure out why my CI/CD build was failing...

Answer (score 18):

I wanted to make a subdirectory stop being a git submodule.  This worked for me:

```
$ mv subdir subdir2
$ git rm --cached subdir
$ mv subdir2 subdir
```

Comment: Good hack :) Works.

Comment: I tried removing the `.git` and `.gitignore` files in the subdirectory, but it turned out I needed to remove the cache too. Worked, thanks!

Comment: I tried without `rename` and it still worked, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It seems the `git add` context is the parent repo ("parent" means the one including the submodule), which triggers the warning.

Try and change its context with:

```
cd _site
git --git-dir=.git --work-tree=. add . 
git --git-dir=.git --work-tree=. commit -m "new files"
```

Don't forget that, if this works, you would still have to go back to the parent repo, and `git add _site`, since the subrepo would have changes.

And you would have to push both.

---

Update January 2017 (2+ years later)

With Git 2.12, you won't see that `prefix_pathspec: Assertion` anymore.

See [commit 2d81c48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d81c48fa7f7679a92c9fe674b53656166ade4f8) (09 Jan 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff), and [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 00880a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00880a17dd1ccad44150c425d5709b767c9326bc), 18 Jan 2017)</sup>

> ### `pathspec`: give better message for submodule related `pathspec` error
>
> Running "`git add a/b`" when "`a`" is a submodule correctly errored
>   out, but without a meaningful error message.

Comment: I get `error: unknown option `git-dir=.git'`. Also, I can't commit my parent repo from within Travis, that will cause an infinite loop of Travis running...

Comment: @jmite I have fixed the answer: the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` are options of the `git` command, not the `git add` command. Try at least the `git add` part, if the `git commit` isn't practical.

Comment: This seems to break something for me, but I was able to find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists)

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're operating on non-initialized submodules (they're basically missing `.git` directories), therefore you should initialize them first and update:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Otherwise if you don't need this submodule anymore, remove it by:

```
git submodule deinit _site
```

or:

```
git rm -f --cached _site
```

and add it again:

```
git add _site
```

Check your current outstanding submodules by: `git submodule status`.

See also: [Why is git erroring with 'Assertion failed' on git add .?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23205961/55075)

Answer (score 5):

It seems my problem is that I was accidentally deleting the `.git` folder of the submodule.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Could you share how you solved it?

Comment: I solved it by changing my script to not delete the .git folder. So I'd advise that you check your script, see if you actually have a .git folder in the directory.

Comment: I do but I want to get rid of it as remote repo no longer exists. It's just easier for us to include its source code as it is.

Comment: You're best bet then is to look at changing the remote repos. Take a look at the `git remote` command.

Answer (score 2):

100% fix for this problem, even if you have more than one submodule directory inside the project:

```
> git submodule foreach --recursive deinit -f --all -- <relative path>
> git add --all -f
```

Comment: `deinit` learned something new.