# How do I push an angular-seed based project to my own git repo?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-stash, angular-seed

So I made a small web app based off of the Angular-Seed project on my local machine. I cloned it from Github and made the project, no problem.

I added all the files/directories without issue, after I deleted the `.git` directory and `.gitignore` file from the angular-seed root directory. Running a `git status` the console reads:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

However when I add, commit and push to my remote repository, the angular-seed directory (along with the rest of the project files) does not show up.

The directory map looks like `/home/user/my-local-repo/angular-seed/` where all the project files are in the `angular-seed` directory. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

git clone --depth=1 {angular seed repo link} mynewproject

cd mynewproject

rm -rf .git

git init

git remote add origin {repo link}

source: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/issues/239

**You might then get a src refspec error, one solution for that is:**

Maybe you just need to commit. I ran into this when I did:

mkdir repo && cd repo
git remote add origin /path/to/origin.git
git add .
Oops! Never committed!

git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
All I had to do was:

git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin master
Success!

source: [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the directory from git and adding it again, like this:

```
git rm --cached directory
git add directory
```

Source:
[Git: fatal: Pathspec is in submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472596/git-fatal-pathspec-is-in-submodule)