# Copy git repo with sub-modules as directory into another repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

Recently I cloned `gRPC` repo from GitHub which has various submodules like `protobuf, zlib,` etc. I have a different repo `X` of my own. Following is what I did.

1. copied `gRPC` folder into folder `X`
2. pushed the changes of `X` into origin master
3. cloned origin master into another repo `Y`
4. Now, I don't see contents of `protbuf, zlib,` etc. in `Y`

Seems I did something wrong in steps 2 and 3. All I wanted to do was put everything from `gRPC` into `X` as clean directory structure. What are the steps to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I removed all `.git` and `.gitmodules` from all directories that I wanted to be part of `X`. Then, for each of those folders did the following as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270959/4825809

```
git rm --cached directory
git add directory
```

Now I can see committed `protobuf` in fresh `clone`.