# Cannot Delete Git/GitHub Repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am totally new to version control of any kind, including: Git and Github. But yesterday I thought I would give it a try for some lecture slides I was working on. You can see my botched attempts at: https://github.com/meaneych

I hastily created a number of repositories. But now I don't want them and would to delete them from Git/Github (I kind of want to undo everything and just start from scratch).

I followed the instruction for deleting repositories at:
https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository
However, when I go to click on the "Delete this repository" button nothing happens (i.e. I don't get prompted with the pop up that should occur at step 4). Why? Have I locked some files, is there some kind of a file access issue, or have I committed some kind of an illegal move that will not allow me to fully delete a repository?

[image]

I also tried to follow the command line instructions given here: [How do I delete a local repository in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514054/how-do-i-delete-a-local-repository-in-git) However, the repositories still remain in Git/Github (I still see them). And also, when in the Mac Github GUI I can't access the `Menu - Edit - Delete` button to try to delete any local or Guthub repositories as shown here:

[image]

I am totally new to Git/Github and just want to start from scratch. How would I delete all these local and Github repositories I made in error? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: popup is likely blocked by your browser? You will have to type the repository name in a popup.

Comment: My pop up blocker was on. But I turned it off (closed all tabs, logged into github again, and gave it another try). And still no luck deleting the repository.

Comment: Sorry it was a Safari issue...still can't delete in Safari. But can delete in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use NoScript or similar addons? It blocks the delete popup for me, if it's activated on the site. If so, try whitelisting github.com.

Edit: unfortunately, I don't have easy access to Safari, so I can't provide help specific to that browser.

Comment: No I do not use NoScript. My Safari preference "Enable JavaScript". My pop up blocker was on. But I turned it off (closed all tabs, logged into github again, and gave it another try). And still no luck deleting the repository. I am using Safari 6 if that helps.

Comment: Sorry it was a Safari issue...still can't delete in Safari. But can delete in Chrome and Firefox.