# Remove repository from Github command line

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub and I was following some online lessons and I accidentally created a repository of my desktop.

I checked my GitHub account via the website and I don't have the repository and I have no idea how to remove it from my desktop, I have no idea what the name of the file is or how it happened.

This is what I see:

[image: Command Line Photo]

Comment: A simple `rm -rf .git` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'll only make that mistake once haha

Answer (score 0):

Note: your GitHub account would only be affected if you add, commit and push to a GitHub repo.

A simple local `git init` only creates a .git sub folder, that can be deleted if the repo has no business to be here in the fist place, as detailed in "[How do I delete a local repository in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1514086/6309)" or "[How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213446/6309)".