# vscode version control always track changes in Desktop

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using vscode + git to work on a project on macOS. It worked as expected before; however, it now constantly tracks changes in Desktop and I don't know how to disable it.
[image]

My project folder is located at Desktop and I want version control only keeps track of files in my project folder. How can I disable or configure it? Currently it tracks all changes in my Desktop.

Comment: So where exactly is/are your git repositories?

Comment: If you don't want to track changes you can remove the local git repository as per these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514054/how-do-i-delete-a-local-repository-in-git in other words, go to your desktop folder and delete the `.git` folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init